# Неверный запрос статических файлов в SPA (React + ASP.Net Core)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

Имеется проблема с запросом статических файлов на страницах с адресом вида /tour/:id.
На сервере в файле Startup.cs в конце метода Configure такая обработка запросов:

```
app.Map("/*", routes => 
{
    app.UseSpa(spa => { spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; });
});
```

На клиенте используется React Router 4

```
<Switch>
    {routes.map(route => {
        return (
            <Route exact={route.exact}
                   path={route.path}
                   component={route.component}
                   key={route.path}/>
        )
    })}
</Switch>
```

Вид роутов:

```
export const routes: IRoute[] = [
    {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: Index
    },
    {
        path: "/tour/:id",
        component: Tour
    },
    {
        path: "/tours",
        component: Tours
    }
];
```

Если переходить по страницам непосредственно через приложение или переходить с внешнего сайта на адрес без параметров (типа /tours), запрос статических файлов работает отлично,

[image: correct]

но если  страницу с адресом типа /tour/12345 обновить через адресную строку (или просто попасть на нее через внешнюю ссылку), то html-ка с сервера приходит правильная, но статические файлы запрашиваются не /css/... или /js/..., а /tour/css... и так далее.

[image: Wrong]

Судя по всему, он почему-то корневым путем начинает считать "/tour" вместо "/".
 Как это исправить?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему. Ошибка была в присылаемом файле html, я в нем пути случайно поставил не /js/main.bungle.js, а js/main.bundle.js, поэтому и неверный путь был.